# Подскажите класс или библиотеку php для работы с email raw

Tags: php, email

Добрый день, разыскивается  класс, который может из различных частей почты собрать raw
на пример

```
$message->setTo($to);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->attach($filename);
$raw = $message->getRaw();
```

и на оборот, из raw извлекать параметры

```
$message->setRaw($raw);
$to = $message->getTo();
$from = $message->getFrom();
$attachments = $message->getAttach();
```

Answer (score 1):

По идее любой класс для отправки email по такому принципу работает. `$raw` выступает как объект.
Гугл выдал первые два результата такие:

1. https://myrusakov.ru/php-class-email.html
2. http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html

Из крупных и популярных: [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) и [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).